# CKEditor Preview Method

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, preview

I would like to have a button elsewhere on my page that runs the same method that clicking the "Preview" button does in the CKEditor toolbar. I'm using jquery so it would be something like this:

```
$('#previewButton').click( function () { 
$('#editor1').ckEditorGet().Preview(); 
});
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? I pored over the API documentation but can't find a word on it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can get the editor contents with `$('#editor1').val()`, and display it the way you prefer. This example uses a popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#previewButton').click( function () {
            var contents = $('#editor1').val();
            var mywin = window.open("", "ckeditor_preview", "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=500,height=500");

            $(mywin.document.body).html(contents);
        });

        $('#editor1').ckeditor();      
    });
</script>

<textarea id="editor1" cols="5" rows="5">
Contents...
</textarea>

<button id="previewButton">Preview</button>
```

Comment: Interesting idea ... I will try it out when I get a chance. The only comment I have is that I don't think you can access the HTML of the CKEditor with the .val() method. You need to do, $("#editor1").ckEditorGet().getData().

Comment: I ended up using this solution as it gives me a lot more control. I did add a few lines to the .click function. Namely: mywin.focus() and return false;. This kept the new window in focus as it opened.

Comment: @MikeMurko The `.val()` method is a dedicated method in the jQuery adapter, so it works this way (see the blog [CKEditor for jQuery](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery)).

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug or other development tool navigate to the "Preview" button in the CKEditor. There you'll find function on the click event like:

```
CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(6, this); return false;
```

You can use it to open a preview window. You can do smth. like:

```
<html><a ... onclick="openPreview(this); return false;"></a></html>
<script>function openPreview(ar_obj){ CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(6, ar_obj); }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you could do something like this

```
$('[title="Preview"]').click();
```

Select the `anchor` with `title=preview` and invoke click.

Comment: Magic, that worked! I'm going to investigate styu's approach as well because I was thinking of doing something *with* the content that gets previewed on the new window and his approach allows me to do that. Thanks for the help!